# Add tag to page title when viewing specific tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-nav

When I am viewing custom tags, the page title is "New Questions". If I open multiple tabs to specific, individual tags I have a bar of "New Questions" tabs.

Can the page title be change to include the list of custom titles that are currently being watched?

New nav:

[image: Title without tags]

Existing functionality:

[image: Existing with title]

Currently this works even if multiple tags are being watched:

[image: Existing with multiple tags in title]

Comment: Yes, please, this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done and will be released in the next deployment.