# Don't add infinitely many tags to the title when browsing favourite tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, title, new-nav

Since [Add tag to page title when viewing specific tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256824/205264), tags you're searching for / looking at are in the page title. I like this.

However, when I browse my favourite tags (https://stackoverflow.com/?tagFilter=favorite), all my favourite tags end up in the title:

> 'android braintree html javascript jquery laravel mysql nginx pdo php spip sql' questions that need answers - Stack Overflow

I find that a bit much. I would suggest either placing a limit on the amount of tags in the title, but even better: if you're looking at your favourite tags, change the title to

> Questions with favorite tags that need answers - Stack Overflow

or something like that.

---

*Note:* I didn't check if infinitely many tags would actually be allowed.

Comment: probably a max of 4294967296? Although there are only 43632 tags on SO.